# appending into a file inside thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written the following function to implement two threads in POSIX. Inside each thread, I want to append a line to a test file named "demo.txt" each time the thread runs. **But nothing is being written in the file.**

My sample code fragment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;
void * threadFunc1(void * arg)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",(char*)arg);
        fprintf(fp,"Looping %d time in threadfunc1",i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void * threadFunc2(void * arg)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;;i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n",(char*)arg);
            fprintf(fp,"Looping %d  time in threadfunc2",i);
            sleep(1);
    }
}


int main(void)
{   
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    fp=fopen("demo.txt","a");

    char * message1 = "i am thread 1";
    char * message2 = "i am thread 2";  

    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,threadFunc1,(void*)message1 );
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,threadFunc2,(void*)message2 );

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Why there isn't anything being written in the file demo.txt? What will I need to correct if anything wrong?

Comment: Have you checked whether any of the functions called fail? In particular whether `fopen()` fails? That said, accessing an object without any synchronization from multiple threads is a recipe for disaster, use a mutex.

Comment: Undefined behavior, overflowing an `int`, infinite loops...

Comment: what is the solution? @EOF

Comment: @user5216540: How should I know without having the question? All I see is code that makes no sense (neither to me, nor to the compiler).

Comment: I just want to append some text into a file from various threads @EOF

Answer (score 0):

In general, such scenarios necessitate the need for synchronization mechanisms. The approach depends on your architecture and requirement.

You might need to implement mutex or semaphore.

Another possible approach for synchronization could be such that every thread treats the file as shared memory using a memory mapped file.

If your scenario demands more reads than writes, then the best synchronization mechanism can be based on reader-writer-lock as it allows more concurrent reads.

Another approach can be having mechanism to ensure that at any point of time, the threads write different parts of file and do not compete for the same location in file.

Comment: Can you please show me a demo code of writing into files inside two threads? @Karthik Balaguru

Comment: How do you get out of threadFunc1 and threadFunc2 ? The loop   for(i=1;;i++) will never exit.  It needs   for(i=1; i<MAXVALUE;i++) , you decide what your MAXVALUE is , or you break inside the loop for a given value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `fflush(fp)` after `fprintf(fp, ...)`. This forces a write buffered data.
`fflush()` not needed if you add `\n` (new line) character at end of your line.

Comment: The `'\n'` only affects line-buffered streams. A file is likely to be opened fully buffered by default.